# extend menu background into right auto margin

Tags: css, responsive-design

This is a responsive design with max-widths and auto left/right margins. I'm trying to get the white menu background to extend across the auto margin ONLY to the right of the menu.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iain_g/322cfzhw/) with the essential elements.
[Screenshot of what I'm after here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyZ3r.jpg)

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="nav-box">
    <nav id="esw-main-menu" role="navigation" tabindex="-1">
        <ul id="main-menu-links">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

div.nav-box:before, div.nav-box:after {
    /*clearfix*/
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
div.nav-box:after {
    clear: both;
}
div.nav-box {
    *zoom: 1;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0;
    background: #5D8BB8;
    box-shadow: inset 0 7px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
nav#esw-main-menu {
    max-width: 40em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
div.nav-box ul {
    margin: 0 0 2em;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 7px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background: white;
    padding:0;
}
div.nav-box ul li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}
div.nav-box ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 1em 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Not seeing your problem. Your Fiddle looks like what you're describing.

Comment: If you pull the result window wider to pass the max-width you'll see the blue background rather than white extending?

Comment: Hey Iain, you need to update your JSFiddle with the CSS from your post. Your Fiddle shows ONLY white background right now.

Comment: While your `ul` is floating right, it won't stretch to 100% of your container. Put another container around it (with your clearfix) and style that container with the white bg and box-shadow.

Comment: That's the problem though, I don't want it to fill 100% - that would be a white bar across the whole width - just want it to extend to the right of where it is now, not on the left. I realise this probably isn't possible, just hoping! – I've reduced the max-width on the fiddle, so hopefully it's more obvious now.

Comment: Yeah, without a screenshot I really don't know what you mean. Could you upload one to imagur and give us a link?

Comment: Thanks Phil, I've updated the original post with the screenshot link. Thanks for looking.

Comment: There may be some hacky ways to make it work. I did it once before with absolute-positioned pseudo elements, but I think it kind of breaks down when you resize the window.